# How to display Count() in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am new to lightning components, I am displaying query result in a lightning component. While displaying the count(Id) in the lightning table, i am facing issue. Can anyone help me to correct the syntax.

Apex class:

```
public class OmniChannelMonitoringClass {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List < AggregateResult > fetchAccts() {
       return [ SELECT Queue.name,count(Id) FROM PendingServiceRouting group by queue.name ];
    }

}
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component controller="OmniChannelMonitoringClass" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
    <aura:attribute type="AggregateResult[]" name="acctList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAccounts}"/>

    <lightning:datatable data="{! v.acctList }" 
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
                     keyField="id"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

 </aura:component>
```

Lightning Controller:

```
({
    fetchAccounts : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Queue Name', fieldName: 'Queue.name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Count', fieldName: 'Count(Id)', type: 'integer'},
            
        ]);
        var action = component.get("c.fetchAccts");
        action.setParams({
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.acctList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Open [chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open) and then go to [networks tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#filter-by-type) filter xhr requests and then search for see what you are getting in the response and then try to fix the binding in the component markup.

Answer (score 1):

When you use an `AggregateResult` you result changes in Apex.

You need to change your backend to not return the `List<AggregateResult>`, to something meaningful, like a map where key will be QueueName and the value as Count.

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregateResults = [SELECT MethodName, COUNT(Id) FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Completed' GROUP BY MethodName];

for(AggregateResult eachAggregateResult : aggregateResults){
    Object methodName = eachAggregateResult.get('MethodName') == null ? 'Total' : eachAggregateResult.get('MethodName');
    Object countexpr0 = eachAggregateResult.get('expr0');
    System.debug(methodName + ' --> ' +countexpr0);
}
```

Result is :

```
16:01:35.17 (27121982)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|handleFeatureFlagSettings --> 1
16:01:35.17 (27205763)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|saveQueueItemsAsync --> 5
16:01:35.17 (27258989)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|Total --> 137
```

Then from javascript you can get the count of the value and show it on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the grouped fields are labeled as `expr0`, `expr1`, and so on. If you use an alias then those are skipped. You can get the result using that alias. You can use this directly in the lightning components apex result.

Just mention that in the column definition.

```
{label: 'Count', fieldName: 'expr0', type: 'integer'},
```

If you are using an alias then need to put the alias instead of `expr*`.

---

Although you can use the default naming, it's recommended to use aliases for example in your query you can rename `Count(Id)` to `pendingCount` like below.

```
SELECT Queue.name, count(Id) pendingCount FROM PendingServiceRouting group by queue.name
```

Then you can use that in the query definition like below.

```
{label: 'Count', fieldName: 'pendingCount', type: 'integer'},
```